# How to force multiple hbm2ddl executions to run separatedly?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hbm2ddl

We deploy our JavaEE applications as WARs in multpile Wildfly-servers. As persistence-framework we use JPA with Hibernate as implementation.

To garantee a matching DB-Schema to our entity-classes we have the following entry in our `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

This is now used for the ease of maintaining a highly volatile DB-schema up-to-date because our domain model is far from stable at the moment.

If we deploy, say 2, WARs (containing the same entities) in a single server instance, both WARs will try to update the DB-schema. We deploy via an Ansible copy task and this results in parallel startup from both WARs and parallel execution of both `hbm2ddl` executions which gives us errors.

The question is now, is there an Hibernate built-in way to prohibit parallel execution of schema migrations via `hbm2ddl`?

Comment: No. Probably you should consider using a tool like Flyway or Liquibase to migrated your database.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli you should post the comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should consider using a tool like Flyway or Liquibase to migrated your database.

- https://flywaydb.org/
- http://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: In a not so far future we'll use liquibase.

Comment: Good choice. I think both frameworks are great. If you use plain SQL I would choose flyway in all other cases Liquibase